# Clamp extruded polygon to 3D Tiles in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

When we add  3D tileset to Cesium, Most of the  time it doesn't align properly with  cesium terrain, due to which some part of the 3D Tiles floats above  or hides below the  cesium Terrain (image attached).
We can get Mean Sea Level reference height from cesium  terrain and all data  can be clamped to terrain easily. I want to clamp extruded polygons to google 3D  Tiles  instead of cesium terrain. Please provide snippet that can help me in either getting the elevation values from 3D tiles instead  of terrain or Clamping an  extruded  polygon to 3D Tiles.
[image]

Comment: see https://bertt.wordpress.com/2023/07/11/adding-objects-to-google-photorealistic-3d-tiles/